# Shell scripting accepting 2 arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have created a shell script called `am.sh` which creates and places text into a file. I now want to create another script which will accept the text file that `am.sh` created, say `words.txt` and a number, so using the command:

```
./bm.sh words.txt 5
```

will output the first 5 words contained in the `words.txt` file.

I'm pretty stuck as all of the scripting I have done up to this point only uses a single argument.  So far what I came up with was:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep '[A-Za-z]' | while read
do
echo " $a "
done
```

but I need a way to accept the number of words the user wants, then I need to create a loop that will output from the text file.

Comment: OK, yes itsyou, this might help you ... https://tecadmin.net/tutorial/bash-scripting/bash-command-arguments/

Comment: First, if you can use bash, then your first line should be `#!/bin/bash`. It will provide much more functionality. To loop over the arguments you can use `for i in "${@}"; do echo $i; done`. `$i` during each iteration will be the next argument to process. Your space-separated arguments will be preserved if quoted. For instance, if your arguments were `my "dog has" fleas`, you have 3 arguments `"my"` then `"dog has"` and finally `"fleas". You can use `"${@:2}"` to get all arguments beginning with the 2nd argument, `"${@:3}"` to begin with the 3rd and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what worked for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

file=$1
word_count=$2
fields=$(echo $(seq 1 $word_count) | sed 's/\s/,/g')

head -n 1 $file | cut -d ' ' -f$fields
```

Positional parameter one (`$1`) has to be the filename of the file that your first script created. The second one (`$2`) is the number of words that should be printed.

I'm assuming that words are delimited by one space.

Comment: Doesn't this rely on the file having at least the relevant number of words on the first line?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the file generated by `am.sh` has one word per line, then you can use:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ $# = 2 ] || { echo "Usage: $(basename "$0" .sh) file numlines" >&2; exit 1; }

sed "${2}q" "$1"
```

The first line of code checks that there are two arguments and indicates how to use the command and exits with an error status if there aren't.

The second line used `sed` to print the first lines of the file.  Equivalently, you could use `head` to print the first lines of the file:

```
head -n "$2" "$1"
```

If perchance the file contains more than one word per line, then you can use:

```
tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' < "$1" |
sed "${2}q"
```

(or `head -n "$2"`).

Note that the script does not verify that `$1` is a file that's readable, nor that `$2` is an integer greater than zero.